# Chart.js not drawing on mobile (safari/chrome) fine on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chart.js

I've got a piechart that works perfectly fine on desktop. It retrieves data from an AJAX request and stores the data/json it gets. Selected data is then pushed into the chart. I am using Thymeleaf & Spring in but thats not relevant here I believe.

Everything is rendered fine on my page when I access it through Safari or chrome on mobile, however the graph is not present.

I've tried changing responsive true/false, maintaingAspectRatio false/true, playing with other options provided in the chart.js documentation. Changed the viewport, set my width on the container of the canvas rather than the canvas it self and a whole bunch of other stuff.

Could it  be due to the load order? i.e the page is loaded before it can actually get the information from the request? However, that would mean that it shouldn't be working on desktop either.

Here is some code

**myGraph.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var id = $.url(2);

$.ajax({
    url: "hosturl/a/b/" + id + "/c/d",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);


        var count = [];
        var days = [];




        for (var i in data) {
            days.push(data[i][1]);
            count.push(data[i][0]);

        }

        var chartdata = {
            labels: days,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "By day",
                    backgroundColor: "#4dc3ff",
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    hoverBackgroundColor: "#009",
                    hoverBorderColor: "#099",
                    hoverBorderWidth: 5,
                    data: count
                }

            ]
        };

        var ctx = $("#daysGraph");


        var pieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: chartdata,
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    position: 'right',
                    labels: {
                        fontColor: "#000"
                    }

                }

            }

        });
    },
    error: function (data) {

    }
});
```

**graph.html** (most of the other html is cut out out, but this on its own doesn't work)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-
scale=1,maximum-scale=7"/>
<title>Hmm</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>

<script src="../../javascript/Chart.min.js" th:href="@{/Chart.min.js}"/>

<script src="../../javascript/js-url-2.5.0/url.js" th:href="@{/url.js}" ></script >

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/graph.css" th:href="@{/css/graph.css}"/>

<script src="../../javascript/myGraph.js"  th:href="@{/myGraph.js}" />



</head>
<body>

<div class="chart-container">
<canvas id="daysGraph" ></canvas>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

**graph.css**

```
.chart-container {
position: relative;
margin: auto;
height: 80vh;
width: 80vw;
```

}

On the live server it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yxWr.png)

Any advice is welcome

Answer (score 1):

Turned out there was something wrong with the api-route on mobile vs dektop relating to localhost. Therefore my data wasn't being fetched from the api and thus wouldn't populate the chart which is why it is not displaying on mobile. In other words, I was looking in the wrong places for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems myself, I resolved my issue by playing around with the borderWidth in order to get it working across all devices. Try changing it several times to see if it has any impact at all.

Comment: I wish it was this easy. I've tried what you suggested. No success however.